# Generic type parameter is not constrained when passing lifetime

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

Why does the following not compile?

```rust
trait A<'a> {
    type Typ;
}

trait B {}

struct C<T> {
    _ph: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<'a, T, V> B for C<T> where
    T: A<'a, Typ=V>
{}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b7634cb21ff64ffca6bb53e562bf8cb)

The previous gives the error "the type parameter `V` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates". Changing the associated type to a generic type also does not compile, giving the same error.
However, the following compiles when the lifetimes are removed.

```rust
trait A {
    type Typ;
}

trait B {}

struct C<T> {
    _ph: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T, V> B for C<T> where
    T: A<Typ=V>
{}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab72a74c6e257613f0a1d94c652d2b1e)

Removing the associated type compiles as well.

```rust
trait A<'a> {}

trait B {}

struct C<T> {
    _ph: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> B for C<T> where
    T: A<'a>
{}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab7074891c57dca9fa38ee8f8f2cc064)

Seeing how just removing the lifetime causes the code to compile (not changing V in any way), I'm guessing the error message is not the real underlying error. I have no clue what the real reason for not compiling would be.

The original situation this arose isn't really relevant - this question's more about the strange behaviour and error message, but you can look at it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=413baf95ffeeb7e5bca2679cd308a020) if you want.

Comment: I think it's because the generic opens up a (possibly infinite) number of `'a` and `V` pairs that satisfy `T: A<'a, Typ=V>`, which means that just given the type `C<T>`, Rust cannot decide what generic `impl` parameters to use. With no lifetime and only a constraint on the associated type, there can only be one `A` impl and thus only one valid `V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains because you are not constraining that generic.

It is like writing:

```rust
impl<A> SomeTrait for MyType {}
// We aren't using A
```

This will work just fine because it is already generic over what `Typ` is:

```rust
impl<'a, T> B for C<T> where
    T: A<'a>,
{
    // you can refer to your V type as <T as A>::Typ
}
```

If you do want to constrain it you can:

```rust
use std::default::Default;

impl<'a, T> B for C<T> where
    T: A<'a>,
    <T as A<'a>>::Typ: Default,
{
    // now here you can call <T as A<'a>>::Typ::default()
}
```